# I am having trouble translating an EBNF grammar to an Antlr4 grammar

Tags: xquery, antlr, antlr4

I have the following EBNF grammar:

```
StringConstructor      ::=      "``[" StringConstructorContent "]``"
StringConstructorContent       ::=      StringConstructorChars (StringConstructorInterpolation StringConstructorChars)*
StringConstructorChars     ::=      (Char* - (Char* ('`{' | ']``') Char*))
StringConstructorInterpolation     ::=      "`{" Expr? "}`"
Char       ::=      #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]
```

And am trying the following in Antlr4 at [xqDoc GitHub repository](https://github.com/lcahlander/xqdoc/tree/master/src/main/antlr4/org/exquery/xqdoc):

XQueryParser.g4

```
stringConstructor: '`' '`' '[' stringConstructorContent ']' '`' '`' ;

stringConstructorContent: stringConstructorChars (stringConstructorInterpolation stringConstructorChars)* ;

stringConstructorChars: ( CHAR* ~ ( CHAR* (('`' '{') | (']' '`' '`')) CHAR* ) ) ;

stringConstructorInterpolation: '`' '{' expr '}' '`' ;
```

XQueryLexer.g4

```
CHAR:   ( '\t' | '\n' | '\r' | '\u0020'..'\u0039' | '\u003B'..'\uD7FF' | '\uE000'..'\uFFFD' ) ;
```

It is for parsing the following:

```
for $s in ("one", "two", "red", "blue")
return ``[`{$s}` fish]``
```

and evaluates to the sequence ("one fish", "two fish", "red fish", "blue fish").

I am getting the following errors:

```
error(50): :494:38: syntax error: missing RPAREN at '*' while looking for rule element
error(50): :494:70: syntax error: extraneous input ')' expecting SEMI while matching a rule
```

Does anyone have a suggestion to fix this?  I have commented out that section of the grammar so that it compiles.

Comment: Are those errors referring to line 494 at columns 38 and 70? If so, which line in the code you provided is line 494 in your file?

Comment: line 494 is the stringConstructorChars in the XQueryParser.g4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating my own Antlr4 grammar instead on trying to automatically convert EBNF to Antlr4.